# Upload large attachment from email to ms graph drive

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to upload large attachment(25MB) to Microsoft Office graph drive.

With Microsoft Graph SDK in ASP.NET, I cannot retrieve attachment(outOfMemory exception is thrown).

```
var attachment = await client.Me.Messages[messageId].Attachments[attachmentId].Request().GetAsync();
```

And even if I somehow get the attachment I think that I will not be able to upload on MS Graph drive, because Attachment class don't have contentBytes property.

When I tried to do that from javascript everything works fine in Chrome, FF but it doesn't work on IE. 
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied. is thrown while contentType is being converted to blob.

```
const byteString = atob(file.contentBytes);
const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
   byteArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}
return new Blob([byteArray], { type: file.contentType });
```

Did someone know the best way to do this?